# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use RESTful controller. Here is my `Route.php`:

```
Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Here is my `TestController.php`

```
<?php
class TestController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
            return View::make('test.home');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
            //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
            //
    }
}
```

My app route is `localhost/Test/public/` and it shows "You have arrived" message. But when I tried `localhost/Test/public/test` It gives me "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

Here is my log:

```
[2014-05-11 14:29:59] production.ERROR: NotFoundHttpException Route: `http://localhost/Test/public/test` [] []
[2014-05-11 14:29:59] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php:5289
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(4663): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(4651): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(4643): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(679): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(1136): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(7218): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(7815): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(7762): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(10768): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\compiled.php(640): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\wamp\www\test\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main} [] []
```

I know this question has been asked many times. I had gone through many relevant threads but just can not figure out the solution.

Comment: Is your controller namespaced?

Comment: No it is not but I also tried removing \ infront of BaseController still not working.

Comment: `NotFoundHttpException` exception in Laravel always means that it was not able to find a router for a particular URL

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A `NotFoundHttpException` exception in Laravel always means that it was not able to find a **router** for a **particular URL**. And in your case this is probably a problem in your web server configuration, virtual host (site) configuratio, or .htaccess configuration.

Your public/.htaccess should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As you can see there is a condition in the first line `IfModule mod_rewrite.c`, so if you don`t have mode_rewrite installed or enabled, all rewrite rules will fail and this

```
localhost/Test/public/
```

Will work fine, but not this:

```
localhost/Test/public/test
```

In other hand, this one should work too, because this is its raw form:

```
localhost/Test/public/index.php/test
```

Because Laravel needs it to be rewritten to work.

And note that you should not be using /public, your URLs should look like this:

```
localhost/Test/
```

This is another clue that your virtual host's document root is not properly configured or not pointing to /var/www/Test/public, or whatever path your application is in.

All this assuming you are using Apache 2.

Comment: Hi Antonio. Thanks for the reply. It seems that something is wrong with .htaccess as when I tried to load localhost/Test/public/index.php/test It is loading the page. But my .htaccess is same as you specified. Also I have one more project on server and it is working fine with url rewrite.

Comment: And that project is also a laravel project made by me few weeks back and it is working fine. But when I tried to start this new project I started getting this error.

Comment: Virtual Host configuration is a per-site-thing, so all of your sites might work and this one not and it may still be your Virtual Host/Apache configuration. The .htaccess only uses web server and Virtual Host features, so it's unlikely it's the source of the problem, since, this is something thousands of developers are using without touching.

Comment: Thanks for the help Antonio. I enabled virtual host module and converted my URL to test.dev and now its working.

Comment: So what is the correct htaccess settings for 3 level alias
i,e 
localhost/Test/public/test

Comment: I use this .htaccess but still error displayed in /app/storage/logs/laravel.log but view displayed

Answer (score 15):

I had this case. I checked all of my codes and my solution was:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Because I forgot to clear the route cache.

Comment: I fucking hate this., Every so often it's always the cache fault after finding solution for days. Thanks for pointing this out, this really helped. From now on I always clear cache before I start my how do I fix this google research crap journey.

Comment: Actualy, that's a good thing. Because Laravel is caching the route for better performance

Answer (score 2):

Before my `web.php` was like below

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
        Route::resource('roles','Admin\RoleController');
        Route::resource('users','Admin\UserController');
    });
```

In url enterd

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/roles

and get the same error. The solution was :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
  Route::resource('roles','Admin\RoleController');
  Route::resource('users','Admin\UserController');
});
```

Remove 'prefix' => 'admin', as both Controllers are located in Admin folder

Answer (score 1):

like Arjan Koole says, I had a similar error

using:

```
Route::get('/performance/{$submit_type}/{$send_selected}/{$date_a}/{$date_b}', 'PerformanceController@calc');
```

instead of

```
Route::get('/performance/{submit_type}/{send_selected}/{date_a}/{date_b}', 'PerformanceController@calc');
```

So be aware when you use {$stuff}

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, the problem was I've used an **extra prefix slash** like:

```
Route::get('/plans', 'PayPalController@getPlansList')->name('paypal.plans');
```

instead of:

```
Route::get('plans', 'PayPalController@getPlansList')->name('paypal.plans');
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I put `{$id}` instead `{id}` in the Route

Answer (score 0):

I have found another situation where this error can occur, and that one has nothing todo with rewrites, for once. It's a very nasty typo :)

I had:

`Route::get('replicas/item/{id}/{?stub}', ['uses' => 'ProductReplicasController@productview', 'as' => 'database.replicas.productview']);`

see the {?stub}, that caused this error with me, it needs to be {stub?} off course. But if you're new to Laravel (like me), that is very easy to miss and could take quite some time to figure out. :)

Answer (score 0):

another thing to check is your document root,

mine was:

www/var

and should be:

www/var/mysite/public

Another reason why I hate web development

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error exception while one project was working but another project with same .htaccess file on same localhost was not working. Turns out since my project directory has capital letter in it, URL also should be capital for routing to work. **localhost/minorweb/public/account** was not working but **localhost/minorWeb/public/account** with W capital was working. 
so, if nothing seems to solve the problem, **check your URL is matched with project directory with case.**

Answer (score 0):

Put this in root `.htaccess` file

The below code do three things :

1. Remove **index.php** from url .
2. Remove **public** from url .
3. fix your problem .

Note : `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`  this code solve your problem my problem was not added `[L]` after `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #Session timeout

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case:
I had to use `POST` method but i was using the `GET!` method in `web.php Rout`