# Laravel error: at /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php : 5289

Tags: laravel

I was having the same issue as seen here: [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593892/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhttpexception-laravel)

However, I guess I was asking my question in the wrong area hence the new post.

I am getting this error constantly (but the site seems to perform fine).  Below is my stacktrace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4663): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4651): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(4643): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(698): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(679): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(1136): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(7218): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(7815): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(7762): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(10768): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php(640): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect www to non-www
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine ON
    SSLCertificateFile /root/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /root/domain.com.ssl/domain.com.ca_bundle.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: My hosts files has the following lines:

```
127.0.0.1 domain.com
127.0.0.1 www.domain.com
```

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue...am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a new install? Did you just update composer?

Comment: Delete the file `/var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php`, try again and replace your error log with the new one.

Comment: Not a new install.  I have deleted the compiled.php and run `php artisan optimize`, which generates it again as this is a production environment (debug=false).  Also, cleared my error log. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK for anyone else who has this error I think I've found the solution.

I had a fairly aggressive error handler which sent me emails on any exceptions thrown:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    // Additional code to email me detailed report on any exception thrown
    ...
}
```

After some digging around I decided to add the following:

```
$this->app->missing(function($exception)
{
    $url = Request::fullUrl();
    Log::warning("404 for URL: $url");
});
```

It appears to me, based on the logs, that each time I was getting the confusing error mentioned above `Laravel error: at /var/www/html/bootstrap/compiled.php : 5289`, that a 404 error went along with it.  So I added additional logic to NOT email me the exception if the code is a 404 error.  Now, I no longer get numerous emails regarding the 'error' when in fact, it's simply a 404 Page not Found error and nothing to be concerned with as far as "OMG there is an error in my application that I need to fix" issue. It's just Laravel's long-winded way of saying the page was not found.