# Laravel 5 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: POST http://localhost/myproject/public/leads

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, phpunit

I use Laravel 5.8 and have test method like this this

```
public function test_store()
{
   $attribute= ['lead_name'=>'test_name','lead_family'=>'test_family'];
   $this->post('/leads', $attribute);
   $this->assertDatabaseHas('leads',  $attribute);
}
```

and controller like this:

```
class LeadController extends Controller
{
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
       Lead::create($request->all());
   }
}
```

and route :

```
Route::resource('/leads', 'App\Http\Controller\LeadController');
```

When I run phpunit show me this error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: POST
>   http://localhost/myproject/public/leads
>
> C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithExceptionHandling.php:118
>   C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:326
>   C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php:120
>   C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:375
>   C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php:197
>   C:\wamp64\www\myproject\tests\Feature\Customer\LeadTest.php:38
>   I test `leads` URL with Postman and it work correctly.

I see and read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593892/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhttpexception-laravel

Comment: can you run `php artisan route:list` and see you have got the intended route

Comment: Yes it's exists. I tested it with postman and it worked correctly.

Comment: In that case i would suggest try clearing your cache and do composer dump autoload. see if that helps

Comment: I do it but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I change to `config\app.php` file

```
'url' =>'http://localhost/myscript_addres/public',
```

To

```
'url' =>'http://localhost/',
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your router like this

```
Route::resource('leads', 'LeadController');
```

Make sure  `LeadController` placed in `app/Http/Controller`

Read [Laravel - Route::resource vs Route::controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller)

Comment: Route is true because I tested it with post man and it worked correctly

Comment: do u have teamviwer?

Comment: I know, but In our office forbidden remote to other

Comment: open the console and run this `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `composer dumpautload` and check