# Octobercms: Class name must be a valid object or a string (routes file)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, octobercms

since a composer update I got this error when I run php artisan route:list :

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class name must be a valid object or a string

I ran some tests and this is the lines where the error should but i don't see why:

```
    use Businessbecause\Users\Controllers\Users;
    Route::get('/users/update/created_at', Users::class .'@update_users_created_at');
```

Do you have any idea why it's not working anymore ? Cause it's the same code than before nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```php
Route::get('/users/update/created_at','Businessbecause\Users\Controllers\Users@update_users_created_at');
```

`Users::class .'` like this it won't work i guess (not sure).

---

Or
pass as array in second param
ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing

```php
use Businessbecause\Users\Controllers\Users;
Route::get('/users/update/created_at', [Users::class ,'update_users_created_at']);
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work for one route file and for the other I use the same method [Users::class] but I get "[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper::getInputStream()"

Comment: I managed to fix the route file issue but the main issue still remain, I can't access any routes on my browser. I always get this non clear message: Undefined
Exception

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Comment: @AmauryLeproux take a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593892/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhttpexception-laravel