# Error in log: Exception\NotFoundHttpException error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I just deployed my Laravel app on `AWS` all things are fine!

In my app, I just link my logs app via a slack channel to send any error logs to it!

The weird thing every second the slack channel got this error:

```
Message
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php(162): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection->handleMatchedRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), NULL)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(639): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(628): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(617): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/app/current/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(38): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 /var/app/current/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#18 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/app/current/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 {main}
Show less
Level
CRITICAL
```

My app is just API links for Vue.js project!

I used all options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593892/symfony-component-httpkernel-exception-notfoundhttpexception-laravel) but nothing works for me!

Comment: What's the URL that triggers the 404? Usually I get that for `favicon` requests when I forget to add one

Comment: @apokryfos the wired thing that I don't have the frontend in my app it just API links for Vue project!

Comment: Can"t you log the URL or any other context to it ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti it just a text!